# Error message while running app: bcrypt and babel runtime

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I just copied files from my instructor, and all should running fine.
Instead I got these error message. Can anybody tell me what to do about this?
Thanks

> Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log:
>   Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
>   While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
>   approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
>   In order to use the native implementation instead, run
>
> ```
> meteor npm install --save bcrypt
> ```
>
> in the root directory of your application.
>   D:\LUCY\WEB DESIGN AND PROGRAMMING\Meteor JS db\Week 2\week_2_image_share.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:348
>   }).run();
>      ^
>
> Error: The babel-runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules 
>   directory. Please run the following command to install it:
>
> meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
>
> at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.babel-runtime.babel-runtime.js (packages\babel-runtime.js:37:9)
>       at fileEvaluate (packages\modules-runtime.js:181:9)
>       at require (packages\modules-runtime.js:106:16)
>       at packages\babel-runtime.js:139:15
>       at packages\babel-runtime.js:150:3
>       at D:\LUCY\WEB DESIGN AND PROGRAMMING\Meteor JS db\Week 2\week_2_image_share.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:295:34
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
>       at D:\LUCY\WEB DESIGN AND PROGRAMMING\Meteor JS db\Week 2\week_2_image_share.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
>       at D:\LUCY\WEB DESIGN AND PROGRAMMING\Meteor JS db\Week 2\week_2_image_share.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:344:5
>   Exited with code: 1
>   Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: Did you do as it said? Run ```meteor npm install --save bcrypt``` and ```meteor npm install --save babel-runtime```

Comment: Yes I did, and still got the same error message.

Comment: Have a backup of the project. Then do a ```meteor reset``` to reset the project. Then give it a go. I've seen that usually, when copy pasting entire projects, a reset of the project makes some errros go away